# Text Typed Into PowerShell on RHEL 7 Corrupt

Tags: linux, powershell, rhel-7

I've just installed PowerShell 6.1 on a RHEL 7 system.  The text generaetd by pwsh is ok but the text typed by the user is just weird.  Here is what I get when I type $PSVersionTable at the pwsh prompt:

```
TFDM==>which pwsh
/usr/bin/pwsh
tfdmlab@cwp05.gl3:/home/tfdmlab
TFDM==>pwsh
PowerShell 6.1.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /home/tfdmlab> $<5>$PSVersionT$<5>
$<5>
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.1.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    6.1.1
OS                             Linux 3.10.0-327.36.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Aug 17 03:02:37 EDT 2016
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0


PS /home/tfdmlab
```

Other commands react similarly; the user typed text looks strange but the command output is perfect.

I really don't know what would cause this to happen.  Is there a configuration parameter that needs to be set?

Thanks!

Comment: Location? Keyboard?

Comment: Does text appear like this as the user types or after they press Enter?

Comment: The text appears this way as the user types.